# Opening PDF only works in netbeans

Tags: java, pdf, file-io, runtime, exec

I have written a program that creates PDF documents. After creating, the PDF's must be opened so it can be printen.

i have the following code, but it only works if i launch from netbeans. Could anyone give me some pointers?

```
 public void openPDF()
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Opening PDF");
            File file = new File(pdfPath+pdfName);
            String absolutePDFpath = file.getAbsolutePath().replace(""+(char)92,""+(char)92+(char)9);
            System.out.println("Path = "+absolutePDFpath);
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + absolutePDFpath);
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens het openen van het PDF"
                    + " document\nFoutcode: 0xFF05");
            Logger.getLogger(PrintJob.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: What other way are you using to launch the program? And what error do you get in that case?

Comment: Please provide details about the exception that you see when running from outside netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

See [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) for a way to open a PDF across different platforms.  Something like this..

```
File file = new File(pdfPath+pdfName);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

---

If the app. needs to support Java 1.5 or earlier (before `Desktop` was available), stick with `exec()`, but implement all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

There are a number of things that using a `Process` requires the programmer to do, for reliable running.  That code does *none* of them.

Answer (score -1):

Probably your code doesn't work because you don't specify environment variables. It should be something like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command to execute", env[]);
```